# Add color to vuetify component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm working with vuetify expansion panel ui component (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels). I'm bot sure how to add color to this. As you can see I've been trying to add color="#26c6da" to multiple components without success.

```
<template>
  <!-- <v-layout align-start > -->

  <!-- <v-layout align-start justify-center row fill-height> -->
  <v-container row fill-height justify-center style="max-width: 1200px" class="mx-auto" color="#26c6da">
    <!-- <v-layout row fill-height=""> -->
            <!-- <v-layout row justify-space-around> -->

      <v-flex  class="mx-auto" color="#26c6da">
        <v-expansion-panel style="max-width: 1200px" class="mx-auto" color="#26c6da" >
          <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i">
            <div slot="header" class="headline font-weight-bold">{{item.header}}</div>
            <v-card >
              <v-card-text class="headline font-weight-bold">{{item.text}}</v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-expansion-panel-content>
        </v-expansion-panel>
      </v-flex>
    <!-- </v-layout> -->
  </v-container>
```

Here is a component codepen link:

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdJKqm?&editable=true&editors=101
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: `style="color: ..."` or `style="background-color: ..."`. The prop `color="..."` expects one of [these values](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/colors#material-colors)

Comment: Some components such as `v-flex` don't have `color` prop. So you must either set custom color in theme and use the relevant class, or style it manually.

Comment: @Traxo I wish you had put a link on setting custom color. But thanks for your answer nonetheless, was helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add a standard style like `style="background:#26c6da;color:white"` to any element you want :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(item,i) in 5" :key="i" style="background:#26c6da;color:white">
        <div slot="header">Item</div>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Any idea how to turn the text white instead of black?

Comment: you're welcome, see my updated answer about changing the text color